# Better way of primary key constraint handling?

Tags: perl, sqlite, primary-key

i have this sqlite table:

`CREATE TABLE frames (videomd5 TEXT, framemd5 TEXT, type TEXT, PRIMARY KEY (videomd5, framemd5))`

As you can see, the table has a combined PRIMARY KEY because it is allowed that one of the fields has the same values but never both at once.

Currently I'm performing a check like this

`SELECT framemd5 FROM frames WHERE framemd5='$digest' AND videomd5='$videomd5'`

before adding something to the table to avoid a PRIMARY KEY CONTRAINTs but i feel there is a better way to handle it. Should i fire the INSERT without checking first and handel the CONSTRAINT afterwards? If so, how is this best done in perl?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use the "OR IGNORE" in your insert, eg:

```
sqlite> create table bla (id INT PRIMARY KEY);
sqlite> insert into bla values (1);
sqlite> insert into bla values (1);
Error: column id is not unique
sqlite> insert or ignore into bla values (1);
sqlite>
```

Refer to the official doc for the details:
http://www.sqlite.org/syntaxdiagrams.html#insert-stmt

Answer (score 0):

As you said yourself - there are two ways, do some benchmarks or select the one which matches your coding style.

I prefer first approach, though, than handling primary key violation exceptions